# ASP.Net Treeview CSS not working

Tags: asp.net, css, treeview

I am trying to change the CSS style and color of the Treeview nodes in ASP.Net web page.  I can change the font-size but I couldn't manage to change the color of the nodes.  Could you please help me?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .treeNode {
        color: #070707;
        font: 14px Arial, Sans-Serif;
    }

    .rootNode {
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #f00;
    }

    .leafNode {
        padding: 4px;
        color: #070707;
    }

    .selectNode {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<asp:TreeView ID="tvData" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvData_SelectedNodeChanged" ShowLines="True">
    <LeafNodeStyle CssClass="leafNode" />
    <NodeStyle CssClass="treeNode" />
    <RootNodeStyle CssClass="rootNode" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="selectNode" />
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Root" Value="0">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Products">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="First Product" />
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Second Product" />
            </asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: what kind of styles did you want to apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply this bit of css and you will get an idea.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .treeNode
    {
        color: #070707;
        font: 14px Arial, Sans-Serif;
    }

    .rootNode
    {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding:5px;
        color: red;
        background-color:#DDD;
        border-radius:10px;
    }

    .leafNode
    {
        padding: 4px;
        color: #070707;
        background-color:Silver;
    }

    .selectNode
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color:Black;
        color:White;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

thank you